# python tkinter button events

Tags: python, button, gridview, tkinter

I have written the following code to list all directories/files in a given path and then write them to a button. How can I use tkinter's events handler so that whenever any button is double clicked within the widget window it calls a new function.

```
def display_toplevel(globpath):
    global row, column
    dir=globpath
    dirs = os.listdir(dir)
    for file in dirs:
        Button(master, width=8, height=4, text=file).grid(row=row, column=column, padx=10, sticky=W)
        column = column + 2
        if column == 10:
            row = row + 3
            column = 0
            column = column + 2
            break
```

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [tkFileDialog](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog)? Quote: "If you want to open or save a file or to choose a directory using a filedialog you dont need to implement it on your own. The module tkFileDialog is just for you."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for single clicks; in the code where you create the button, add the `command = # function` parameter:

```
Button(master, width=8, height=4, text=file,command=my_funct).grid(row=row, column=column, padx=10, sticky=W)
# note how the function does not have parentheses (after command=) 

def my_funct():
    # code
```

Reference: [Tkinter Button Widget and Parameters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm)

Comment: thank you, i was looking at the events binding and overlooked something so trivial

Comment: @bigl: You'll need to define the function before binding it, of course.